# EADemo example is always displaying 'No Accessories connected'

Tags: ios, mfi, wac

I have an MFI program license and i'm trying to implement the WAC feature (Wireless Accessory Configuration). Every time I run the EADemo application whether on a real iPhone or on the simulator I get no accessories connected although I'm displaying accessories through the HomeKit tool from xCode is there any solution for this ?

PS: in my info.plist i didn't know what is the protocol of a simulated accessory.
[image]

Comment: The discussion under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397538/protocol-string-name-in-eademo-code) may help you.

Comment: Thank you but i didn't help as well

Comment: @Marwa any luck?

Answer (score 1):

**Add Info.plist**

I have added below in info.plist. EADemo application is working on my side. Make sure your MFi device has connected through device setting.

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.example.apple-samplecode.data</string>
        <string>com.yourcompany.serialtunnel.data</string>
        <string>com.apple.p1</string>
        <string>com.demo.control</string>
        <string>com.demo.data</string>
    </array>
```

**Also need to change** 
[image]